# Memory leak in opencv/c++-cli

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I have a c++-cli/opencv program that is running fine but it has a memory leak in part of it. I included the part where the memory leak is the most. 
I already fixed the leaks in contour0 and contour1 and that reduced the memory leak by 1/3, but there is still a leak somwehere. Is there a way to still reduced memory leak? Thanks.

```
// capture video frame and convert to grayscale
     const int nFrames0 = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty( capture0 , CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ); 
     printf("LICENSECOUNT=%d\n",nFrames0);
     img = cvQueryFrame( capture0 );

     IplImage* frame1;
     cvReleaseImage(&frame1);
     frame1=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );
     cvConvertImage(img, frame1,0);

// create blank images for storing
     cvReleaseImage(&img00);
     img00=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 3 );
     cvReleaseImage(&img10);
     img10=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );
     cvReleaseImage(&img20);
     img20=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );
     cvReleaseImage(&img30);
     img30=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );
     cvReleaseImage(&imggray1);
     imggray1=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );
     cvReleaseImage(&imgdiff);
     imgdiff=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );
     cvReleaseImage(&imgco);
     imgco=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),img->depth, 1 );

     int flagp=1;
     int licf=0;


    CvSeq *contour0; 
CvSeq* result0;

storage0 = cvCreateMemStorage(0); 



     CvRect r0;
//skip a few frames 
      for (int i=0;i<cf1-1;i++)

     img = cvQueryFrame( capture0 );

// go through all frames to find frames that contain square with certain dimension
     while ( key != 'q')
     {
         img = cvQueryFrame( capture0 );
              if( !img ) break;

        cvConvertImage(img,img00,0);    

          cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(0,img->height-35,img->width,35));
          cvZero(img);
          cvResetImageROI(img);


          cvConvertImage(img, img10,0);
          cvConvertImage(img, img20,0);
          cvConvertImage(img, imggray1,0);

       int flagp=1;

       cvAbsDiff(img10,frame1,imgdiff);
           cvThreshold(imgdiff, imgdiff,60,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);


     mem0 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);


     CvSeq *ptr,*polygon;

 //vary threshold levels for segmentation 
     for (int thr=1;thr<11;thr++)

     {
         // do morphology if segmentation does not work
         if (thr==10)
         {

          cvEqualizeHist( img20, img10 );
          cvSetImageROI(img10,cvRect(0,0,20,img->height));
          cvZero(img10);
          cvResetImageROI(img10);
          cvMorphologyEx(img20,img10,img20,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(20,10,10,5,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),CV_MOP_TOPHAT,1);

  IplImage  *frame_copy1 = 0; 
  frame_copy1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img10->width,img10->height),IPL_DEPTH_16S,1 ); 
  cvSobel(img10,frame_copy1,1,0,3); 
  cvConvertScaleAbs(frame_copy1, img10, 1, 0);
  cvSetImageROI(img10,cvRect(0,0,20,img->height));
  cvZero(img10);
  cvResetImageROI(img10);

  cvSetImageROI(img10,cvRect(img->width-20,0,20,img->height));
  cvZero(img10);
  cvResetImageROI(img10);


cvMorphologyEx(img10,img10,img20,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(16,5,8,3,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),CV_MOP_CLOSE,1);




cvThreshold(img10,img10,180,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

cvErode(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(10,5,5,2,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);
cvErode(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(5,10,2,5,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);

cvDilate(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(5,10,2,5,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);
cvDilate(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(10,5,5,2,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);

cvErode(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(10,5,5,2,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),2);
cvDilate(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(10,5,5,2,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);


         }

  //segmenation
         else 


             {
  cvThreshold(img20,img10,thr*255/11,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    cvDilate(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(10,5,5,2,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);
cvDilate(img10,img10,cvCreateStructuringElementEx(20,30,10,15,CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL),1);

    }

   //trim the sides of the image

cvSetImageROI(img10,cvRect(0,0,20,img->height));
cvZero(img10);
cvResetImageROI(img10);

cvSetImageROI(img10,cvRect(img->width-20,0,20,img->height));
cvZero(img10);
cvResetImageROI(img10);


cvReleaseImage(&imgco);

imgco = cvCloneImage(img10); 


///find contours to find squares with certain dimension
cvRelease((void**)&contour0);
int Nc0;
Nc0= cvFindContours(imgco, storage0, &contour0, sizeof (CvContour), 
             CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); 


float k;
int white=0;

while( contour0 )

{

r0 = cvBoundingRect(contour0, 0);
double s,t;
if( ((r0.width*r0.height)>2000 ||  (r0.width*r0.height && thr==10)>1000) && (r0.width*r0.height) < 40000 && (float(r0.width)/float(r0.height))>1.7 && (float(r0.width)/float(r0.height))<5   )  
{

    k=0.8;
if (thr==10 && licf<2)
    k=0.6       ;

   cvSetImageROI(img10,r0);

cc=cvCountNonZero(img10);


cvResetImageROI(img10);

//if area of contour is a percentage of area of rectangle surrounding contour
if (cc>k*r0.width*r0.height && (cvCountNonZero(imgdiff)>10000))
    {   

cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(0,img->height-35,img->width,35));
cvSet(img, cvScalar(255,255,255));
cvResetImageROI(img);

      //process the image contained inside the contour area 
cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(r0.x-5,r0.y-10,r0.width+10,r0.height+20));

img30 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);  

         cvCvtColor( img, img30, CV_RGB2GRAY );  

         IplImage* img_temp=cvCreateImage(cvSize(2*r0.width,2*r0.height+20),img->depth, 1 );
         IplImage* img_tempo=cvCreateImage(cvSize(2*r0.width,2*r0.height+20),img->depth, 1 );


         cvResize(img30,img_tempo);


CvMemStorage *storage1; 
    CvSeq *contour1; 
    CvSeq* result1;

    storage1 = cvCreateMemStorage(0); 
    CvRect r1;

    //segment inside squares check if square contains letters or numbers with certain dimension

    for (int th=20;th<200;th+=5)

 {
    cvThreshold(img_tempo, img_temp, th, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cvThreshold(img_temp, img_temp, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);           

    {
cvErode(img_temp,img_temp);


cvDilate(img_temp,img_temp);
cvErode(img_temp,img_temp);

    }

    cvResize(img_temp,img30);

    cvRelease((void**)&contour1);


    int Nc=cvFindContours(img30, storage1, &contour1, sizeof (CvContour), 
             CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) ;

    int count =0 ;

    while( contour1)


        {

            r1 = cvBoundingRect(contour1, 0);

            int s_y1av=0;
            int s_y2av=0;
            int s_x1av=0;


        {


        int s_x1=r1.x; 

        int s_y1=r1.y;

        float width1=r1.width;

        float height1=r1.height;

        float ratio1= width1/height1;


        //if contours match certain dimensions

        if(ratio1>0.05 && ratio1<1 && height1>0.3*r0.height && width1>0.05*r0.width && width1<0.3*r0.width && width1*height1>60 && width1*height1<2000)

        {  
            count+=1;

        }

        s_y1av=s_y1;
        s_y2av=s_y1+height1;

        }
        contour1=contour1->h_next;
        }

            //if there are more than 3 letters/numbers and less than 9  
        if (count>=3 && count<9)
            {
                th=200;
                thr=11;
                if (thr!=10)
                licf=1;

                if (a)
                {
                cvNamedWindow( "license", 1 );
                cvShowImage( "license", img00 );
                cvWaitKey(1);
                }       


    int jpeg_params[] = { CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 80, 0 };
    CvMat* buf0 = cvEncodeImage(".jpeg", img00, jpeg_params);
    int img_sz=buf0->width*buf0->height;
    array <Byte>^ hh = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz);
    Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)buf0->data.ptr, hh, 0, img_sz );


    if(!myResult->TryGetValue("PLATE", thisList4))
        {
            thisList4 = gcnew List<array<Byte>^>();
            myResult->Add("PLATE", thisList4);}

    thisList4->Add(hh);



             }
        cvResetImageROI(img);

            }

       }



         }

contour0=contour0->h_next;
}


     }



     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some memory leak detection tools i.e. Valgrind could be helpful and good way to start debugging as well.

Comment: Why are you going to suggest a tool that is going to do the dirty work? When you program in any low-level language you assume the right to manage your memory the way he chooses.

Comment: I thought context was to debug the program and not rewrite. May be I interpreted differently.

Comment: I get your point but it is best to learn from mistakes especially if he/she is new to programming. I mean tools are great but they can be come a depedency.

Answer (score 1):

The newer OpenCV C++ interface automatically handles memory for you - allocations and deallocations. You should look at a sample in the samples/cpp folder and take it as a model.

With it, you can forget about memory leaks.

A part of your code written with the new interface will look like

```
VideoCapture cap("SomeVideo.avi");
if(!cap.isOpen())
    return 0;

const int nFrames = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT );
...
cv::Mat img;
cap >> img;
```

You should keep in mind that all the functions and data types that start with cv.., like CvSeq, are from the C interface, and there is a better counterpart in C++.

For example:

- IplImage -> cv::Mat
- CvPoint -> cv::Point
- CvSeq -> std::vector<>

etc. 
Most of the functions in the new interface keep the same name, just without "cv". I wrote above the main exceptions to the rule.

By the way, some of your operations seem to be redundant or inefficient. You should look carefully to see which of them are needed, and also to reuse some matrices, in order to minimize memory allocations.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the new improved smart pointers in C++11. It won't provide automatic garbaje collection but at least it deals with the pain of C++ memory managment. You can also take a look at JavaCV it is just a wrapper but takes away some of the pain of the memory leaks.

If you are not using the latest C++ standard then take a look in autoptr. If not it could be a bug with OpenCV.